# Weird aliasing going on with horizontal lines. Jagged textures and shadows

Tags: rendering, settings

So I have constructed this scene. Showing the scale of something vs manhattan. I have put a small marble on the rooftop but this marble is all messed up.

Here you can see it's all jittery

[image]

and here you can see what it looks like in render mode. Notice the shadows.

[image]

I feel like it may be related to the scale of the scene. However, I tested it on another scene with the same scale and there is no problem. It's also happening on the table although it's not as visible. I have no idea what is causing it. I'm trying to look around the settings to see why it just seems to be happening here.

Problem persists with Eevee too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your scene is huge, and your scene is centered somewhere that the positional values are changing every frame due to floating point precision errors.

Try to move everything so that this is closer to 0,0,0 in world space.

It could also be too large a range in the *Camera Clipping* setting, and perhaps it'd be better for you to split this up into two layers and composite together later.

Comment: Thank you! Moving everything closer to the origin fixed it.